# Stuck on how to $push data into nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb

On my main object in my DB, I have a property that is an array of 7 items (days). In each day is another array of restaurants.

I am struggling to $push data into a specific day array.

In my DB, I want the data structure to look like this

```
restaurants_cook_for: [
{
    monday: [{
        rest_name: rest_name,
        is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
        turn_off_event: false
    },
    {
        rest_name: rest_name,
        is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
        turn_off_event: false

    }]
},
{
    tuesday: [{
        rest_name: rest_name,
        is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
        turn_off_event: false
    }]
}
]
```

In my API file, I have things looking like this but . I cant seem to get it to post into the Monday or Tuesday etc array.

```
const query = { userid: req.body.userid };
const rest_name = req.body.rest_name;
const day_or_night = req.body.day_or_night;
const dayOfWeek = req.body.day_of_week;
const arrayFilters = { arrayFilters: [{ dayOfWeek: 0 }], upsert: true};

const update = {
    $push: {
        "restaurants_cook_for.$[dayOfWeek]": [{
                rest_name: rest_name,
            is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
                turn_off_event: false
            }]

    }
};

ChefProfile.update(query, update, arrayFilters, (err, raw) => {

    if (err) throw err;
    if (raw) {

        console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(raw));
        console.log("1 document updated");
        res.sendStatus(200);

    }
});
```

My Model file is a bit ugly right now since I am trying to also figure out a way to pass in dayOfWeek variable and make it dynamic. I am currently relying on "strict: false" for this.

```
const schemaOptions = {
    collection: "chefs",
    strict: false

};

const ChefProfile = new mongoose.Schema({

    restaurants_cook_for: [{

    }]

}, schemaOptions);
```

When I tinker around I will either get no errors but nothing has been added OR I will get an entire new monday object when really I just wanted to add a restaurant to the monday array.

I feel like I am WAY off here. Any help or push in the right direction would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can convert the restaurants_cook_for array into a days object:

```
restaurants_cook_for: {
    monday: [{
        rest_name: rest_name,
        is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
        turn_off_event: false
    },
    {
        rest_name: rest_name,
        is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
        turn_off_event: false
    }],
    tuesday: [{
        rest_name: rest_name,
        is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
        turn_off_event: false
    }],
    ...
};
```

And then in the query, update only the specific day:

```
const update = {
    $push: {
        `restaurants_cook_for.${dayOfWeek}`: {
            rest_name: rest_name,
            is_night_or_day_shift: day_or_night,
            turn_off_event: false
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: There is a change in the model, the days are now properties of an object. Also the query changed: \`restaurants_cook_for.${dayOfWeek}\` instead of "restaurants_cook_for.$[dayOfWeek]", and use the object instead of wrapping it in an array.